# How to get the single user profile from UPS using powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am new to Powershell world. I want to fetch the single user data from the UPS using Powershell instead of looping through each and every user in the UPS.
I followed  [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192802/powershell-how-to-pull-user-by-email-from-user-profile-store-in-sharepoint/229580#229580) also. Here they are comparing Email with UPS Email and then they are fetching the profile of matched Email in UPS.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$emailAddress = "EMAIL ADDRESS YOU WISH TO QUERY"
$site = Get-SpSite $mySitesURL;
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$allProfiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
foreach ($profile in $allProfiles) {
    if ($profile.GetProfileValueCollection("WorkEmail") -eq $emailAddress) {
        $profile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. Try this:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$emailAddress = "EMAIL ADDRESS YOU WISH TO QUERY"
$site = Get-SpSite $mySitesURL;
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$userProfile  = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()| Where-Object {$_["WorkEmail"].value -like $emailAddress}
```

It will fetch only single user data based on the `$emailAddress`. You don't need to loop through each and every user profile in UPS.

Comment: No problem @SMD :)